# Configurable products import doesn't work configurable_variations not imported

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3

I am trying to import configurable products using a script. All products imported successfully but child product is not associated with the parent in case of configurable. Please check below script & attached CSV.

```
$this->eavConfig->clear();
    $importModel = $this->importModel;
    $importModel->setData(
        [
            'entity' => 'catalog_product',
            'behavior' => 'append',
            'import_images_file_dir' => 'pub/media/catalog/product',
            Import::FIELD_NAME_VALIDATION_STRATEGY =>
                ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface::VALIDATION_STRATEGY_SKIP_ERRORS
        ]
    );

    $source = $this->csvSourceFactory->create(
        [
            'file' => 'Setup/fixtures/product.csv',
            'directory' => $this->readFactory->create(
                $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Custom_Catalog')
            )
        ]
    );

    $currentPath = getcwd();
    chdir(BP);
    $importModel->validateSource($source);


    try {
        $this->importModel->importSource();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $e->getMessage();
    }

    chdir($currentPath);

    $this->eavConfig->clear();
```

[image]
My observations on the above code are as below
1)If I put qty more than 1
2)If I run the above script 2 times it is working.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Try enabling flat categories and products